# cocos2d popscene event

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

How can I let the other scene that gets popped know about the popscene event?  The other scene goes back into view, but now I want something to happen and I can't figure out the best way to trigger it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use onEnter, onEnterTransitionDidFinish or onExit methods of CCNode. Implement methods what you want to know about, in your class that is derived from CCScene.

```
- (void)onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];

    /*
     * This method is called every time the CCNode enters the 'stage'.
     */
}

- (void)onEnterTransitionDidFinish
{
    [super onEnterTransitionDidFinish];

    /*
     * This method is called when the transition finishes.
     */
}

- (void)onExit
{
    [super onExit];

    /*
     * This method is called every time the CCNode leaves the 'stage'.
     */
}
```